# How do I authenticate on ImageView's click, instead of TwitterButton's click

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

Following is the code from [Fabric Docs](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/authentication.html). How can I assign `setCallback()` into `ImageView` because I need to do authentication after `ImageView` is clicked (not `TwitterButton`):

```
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton;
...

loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
   @Override
   public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
       // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
   }

   @Override
   public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
       // Do something on failure
   }
});
```

and after that how can I pass the result to the ImageView back?

Again, code from mentioned website:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result to the login button.
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you hide the `TwitterButton` and delegate your `ImageView`'s clicks to it?

Comment: @Sufian I tried to put `TwitterButton`, but it looks that it is disabled... Why is that? (I've got `Twitter` installed on the mobile phone).

Comment: Ok. This was because I've got `TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig(getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key), getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));` and `Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));` after `setContentView(layout.xml)`...

Comment: Have you solved it now?

Comment: Yes, it works now.

Comment: Post as answer the solution you came up with, and mark it as answer. This will help someone who comes across this in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution.

You need to write `TwitterLoginImageView.class`:

```
public class TwitterLoginImageView extends ImageView {
    final static String TAG = TwitterCore.TAG;
    static final String ERROR_MSG_NO_ACTIVITY = "TwitterLoginImageView requires an activity."
            + " Override getActivity to provide the activity for this button.";

    final WeakReference<Activity> activityRef;
    volatile TwitterAuthClient authClient;
    OnClickListener onClickListener;
    Callback<TwitterSession> callback;

    public TwitterLoginImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public TwitterLoginImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0); // 0 = no style will be applied
    }

    public TwitterLoginImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        this(context, attrs, defStyle, null);
    }

    TwitterLoginImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle,
                       TwitterAuthClient authClient) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.activityRef = new WeakReference<>(getActivity());
        this.authClient = authClient;
//        setupImageView();

        super.setOnClickListener(new LoginClickListener());

        checkTwitterCoreAndEnable();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void setupImageView() {
//        final Resources res = getResources();
//        super.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
//                res.getDrawable(com.twitter.sdk.android.core.R.drawable.tw__ic_logo_default), null, null, null);
//        super.setCompoundDrawablePadding(
//                res.getDimensionPixelSize(com.twitter.sdk.android.core.R.dimen.tw__login_btn_drawable_padding));
//        super.setText(com.twitter.sdk.android.core.R.string.tw__login_btn_txt);
//        super.setTextColor(res.getColor(com.twitter.sdk.android.core.R.color.tw__solid_white));
//        super.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
//                res.getDimensionPixelSize(com.twitter.sdk.android.core.R.dimen.tw__login_btn_text_size));
//        super.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
//        super.setPadding(res.getDimensionPixelSize(com.twitter.sdk.android.core.R.dimen.tw__login_btn_left_padding), 0,
//                res.getDimensionPixelSize(com.twitter.sdk.android.core.R.dimen.tw__login_btn_right_padding), 0);
//        super.setBackgroundResource(com.twitter.sdk.android.core.R.drawable.tw__login_btn);
        super.setOnClickListener(new LoginClickListener());
//        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
//            super.setAllCaps(false);
//        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the {@link com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback} to invoke when login completes.
     *
     * @param callback The callback interface to invoke when login completes.
     * @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException if callback is null.
     */
    public void setCallback(Callback<TwitterSession> callback) {
        if (callback == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Callback cannot be null");
        }
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    /**
     * @return the current {@link com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback}
     */
    public Callback<TwitterSession> getCallback() {
        return callback;
    }

    /**
     * Call this method when {@link android.app.Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)}
     * is called to complete the authorization flow.
     *
     * @param requestCode the request code used for SSO
     * @param resultCode the result code returned by the SSO activity
     * @param data the result data returned by the SSO activity
     */
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == getTwitterAuthClient().getRequestCode()) {
            getTwitterAuthClient().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the activity. Override this method if this button was created with a non-Activity
     * context.
     */
    protected Activity getActivity() {
        if (getContext() instanceof Activity) {
            return (Activity) getContext();
        } else if (isInEditMode()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ERROR_MSG_NO_ACTIVITY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }

    private class LoginClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkCallback(callback);
            checkActivity(activityRef.get());

            getTwitterAuthClient().authorize(activityRef.get(), callback);

            if (onClickListener != null) {
                onClickListener.onClick(view);
            }
        }

        private void checkCallback(Callback callback) {
            if (callback == null) {
                CommonUtils.logOrThrowIllegalStateException(TwitterCore.TAG,
                        "Callback must not be null, did you call setCallback?");
            }
        }

        private void checkActivity(Activity activity) {
            if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
                CommonUtils.logOrThrowIllegalStateException(TwitterCore.TAG,
                        ERROR_MSG_NO_ACTIVITY);
            }
        }
    }

    TwitterAuthClient getTwitterAuthClient() {
        if (authClient == null) {
            synchronized (TwitterLoginImageView.class) {
                if (authClient == null) {
                    authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
                }
            }
        }
        return authClient;
    }

    private void checkTwitterCoreAndEnable() {
        //Default (Enabled) in edit mode
        if (isInEditMode()) return;

        try {
            TwitterCore.getInstance();
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            //Disable if TwitterCore hasn't started
            Fabric.getLogger().e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
            setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Next add `TwitterLoginImageView` as your `ImageView` to the layout file. E.g.:

```
<com.example.fam_app.utils.TwitterLoginImageView
                android:id="@+id/ttImageView"
                style="@style/socialLoginImageStyle"
                android:src="@drawable/twitter_white"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/tt_icon" />
```

After that you need to initialize this `TwitterLoginImageView` in your `Activity`/`Fragment` file:

using `ButterKnife`:

```
@BindView(R.id.ttImageView)
TwitterLoginImageView ttImageView;
```

using standard method:

```
TwitterLoginImageView ttImageView;
```

and in `onCreate()` method:

```
ttImageView = (TwitterLoginImageView) findViewById(R.id.ttImageView);
```

Finally, you need to continue with this site: [Authentication - Log in with Twitter | Fabric.io](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/authentication.html#log-in-with-twitter).

That helps me!

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to write additional classes for that purpose. You can do twitter login with any custom layout. I have already answered a question which is similar to yours.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44165346/7773813) link.