# How to add setCallback to an imageView using Fabric

Tags: android

I am trying to login twitter users from my application, for this I am using Fabric, but says that I must implement the following button to use setCallBack

```
twitter_login_button.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {

            TwitterSession session = result.data;
            String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
            twitter_login_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

        @Override

        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

            Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);

        }

    });

<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
    android:id="@+id/twitter_login_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

However, I want to do it from an image. How can I do this

Method for share

```
 public void shareTwitter(){
            try {

                URL url=new URL("https://www.youtube.com");

                TweetComposer.Builder builder=new TweetComposer.Builder(getContext()) .text(user.getName()) .url(url);

                builder.show();
            }

            catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895231/how-do-i-authenticate-on-imageviews-click-instead-of-twitterbuttons-click

Comment: Not work for me

Comment: Is `twitter_login_button` 's type `Android Button`?

Comment: Not your type is <com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with any image or custom button. For that in your activity 
declare

```
private TwitterAuthClient twitterAuthClient;
```

Find your layout(in my case its a linearlayout)

```
twitter_login = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_twitter_login);
final TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(authConfig)
                .debug(true)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);
        twitterAuthClient = new TwitterAuthClient();

twitter_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                twitterAuthClient.authorize(LoginActivity.this, new com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback<TwitterSession>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                        // The TwitterSession is also available through:
                        // Twitter.getInstance().core.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                        TwitterSession session = result.data;
                        twitterAuthClient.requestEmail(session, new com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void success(Result<String> result) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Twitterkit email id get success = " + result.data);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Twitter kit twitter email get failed");
                                exception.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Twitter kit twitter login failed");
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Then paste add this on your onActivityResult()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    twitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Thats it. Now your twitter login should work

**UPDATED:**

From TwitterKit3 onward you can easily setup Twitter login using twitter sdk instead of fabric

So for login and authentication add this to your gradle

```
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0'
```

And I replaced in my original answer

```
Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```

with

```
TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(authConfig)
                .debug(true)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);
```

And the rest are same

Comment: Happy to help @petereyn

Comment: What kind of exception?

Comment: TwitterException exception Log.e(TAG, "Twitter kit twitter login failed");

Comment: Can you show me the code you are using for the share dialog and the stacktrace

Comment: I already loaded the code of my method to share and I think I also put it in your answering by error. Sorry!

Comment: I will get you to you. Meanwhile you should also upgrade from Fabric to TwitterKit3. Follow [this](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/fabric) link. I have updated my answer

Comment: I'm going to make the changes and I'll tell you